# Dynamically skip particular tests in testng

Tags: java, testing, annotations

I'm trying to skip particular tests based on some condition using annotation transformers http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers

Here is my class

```
public class MyDisabledTest implements IAnnotationTransformer {


    @Test(enabled=false)
    public void testDisabled() {
        System.out.println("This is a disabled test");
    }

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass,
            Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if ("testDisabled".equals(testMethod.getName())) {
            annotation.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my xml

```
<suite name="MyTestNGSuite" parallel="methods"
    data-provider-thread-count="3" thread-count="3">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.walmart.gls.demo_package.MyDisabledTest"/>
  </listeners>
  <test name="MyTestNGTest">
    <classes>
      <class name="MyDisabledTest">
        <methods>
          <include name="testDisabled" />
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

I'm trying to enable the test which has been disabled at compile time. 
What am I getting wrong here?
I'm not getting anything printed on console.

Comment: You're example works for me once I change `<class name="MyDisabledTest">` to `<class name="com.walmart.gls.demo_package.MyDisabledTest">`; otherwise I get `org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot find class in classpath: MyDisabledTest`.

Comment: @mfulton26 it's just a package hierarchy. I have a package hierarchy of com.blah_blah... I know there a way to do that with XML file programmatically. I'm missing somewhere.

Comment: *without XML file. sorry

Comment: Yes, it is just a package hierarchy. My point from my comment though is that your question leaves nothing to solve. If your example works (other than needing to make a minor edit so that your testng.xml actually references your class by using its fully qualified name) then what problem are we trying to solve?

If your actual code doesn't work and it is patterned after your example code in this question then you need to figure out how you're deviating from your example code.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. @mfulton26. Can u please send me the link to your code. I'm sure I will definitely get from that. I don't understand what am I missing. Thanks in advance.